# Reading files into Ruby Numo::NArray

Tags: ruby, narray, nmatrix

I have given number of files, which all have the same size. What I'm trying to do is to load those files into [Numo::Narray](https://github.com/ruby-numo/numo-narray) in a way that every file needs to be in a different row of this array. Number of files and their size is known before creating Narray. What I'm using now is 8-bit unsigned int.

Example: For 5 files of size 512 I would need multidimentional array of shape [5, 512]. Data should be stored in Galois fields. It's crucial as this matrix is going to be used in mathematical operations. What I'm using now to store data is binary data converted 8-bit unsigned int array.  Sadly, performance of ruby's "read" and "unpack('*C')" methods is not high enough.

I have done this with old version of [NArray](https://github.com/masa16/narray), but the performance was not good enough, since I had to first create NMatrix of fixed size filled with zeros, load data to normal Ruby array and replace NMatrix's given row. This new library is quite large and I can't find methods that would e.g. insert row or dynamically add data to row. Do I have to declare fixed NArray or maybe there is a way to do it dynamically by loading data directly from file.read method into Narray so I don't have to create helper ruby array?

Would appreciate optimal solution as I'm interested in high performance.

Comment: Here is a link that can provide some answers: https://github.com/ruby-numo/numo-narray/issues/192

Comment: You said the data format is ASCII format, what is the delimiter for the integer values?

Comment: What I didn't mention is that matrix data needs to be stored in finite/Galois fields. It all comes down to this as I have to perform matrix operations in Galois fields. Currently I'm reading binary file with ruby's "read" and "unpack('C*')" methods, so it stores data in ruby's regular array as 8-bit int. Sadly Performance too slow. I've heard that Numo::NArray has methods like "store_binary" and "from_binary", so now it all comes down to converting file into a binary string and converting it to NArray but ruby is kinda slow on that matter. I guess I have to ask another question.

Comment: It seems that the file format is 8-bit unsigned integer binary data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there are 512 integers stored as 8-bit unsigned integer binary data in the files data0 ~ data4. Then, you can store the 8-bit unsigned integer values from each file in each row of Numo::UInt8 array as follows,

```
require "numo/narray"

n, m = 5, 512

string = ""
n.times do |k|
  string.concat File.binread("data#{k}", m)
end

na = Numo::UInt8.from_binary(string, [n,m])
```

This code combines the string data that should be converted to NArray into a single string and reads it with `Numo::Uint8.from_binary`. However, when I tried it in my environment, it is rate-limiting in the file loading part, and I don't think the `from_binary` method is too slow.

If you are currently using HDD as a strage, you may want to consider using SSDs or other faster storage devices.